# WPF custom control does not use default style of ToggleButton

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I'm creating a custom control which is based on a ToggleButton.
With this simple style in Generic.xaml I can't get the default togglebutton styles working on my custom control.

I'm setting the foreground, background and borderbrush to the systemcolors, but nothing happens.

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:PopupButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="22" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:PopupButton}">
          <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0">
              <ToggleButton.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                  <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                    RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                </ControlTemplate>
              </ToggleButton.Template>
              <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="true" />
            </ToggleButton>
          </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

I've overridden the defaultstylekey:

```
public class PopupButton : ToggleButton
  {
    static PopupButton()
    {
      DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(PopupButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(PopupButton)));
    }
// ...
```

Been testing, playing around with other (xaml) code but after a few hours I still have not figured out why the default style is not applied.

Comment: Well you are changing the ControlTemplate how do you expect to look the same.

Comment: @R.Rusev I'm adding a togglebutton for the controltemplate

Comment: you are overriding it's template as well   <ToggleButton.Template>.

Comment: give me a coffee, please.  https://jeromiewilliamsdotcom.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/i-see-what-you-did-there.jpg?w=900

Comment: but it still doesn't explain to me why my background and foreground is not applied, even if I remove the override the template and set a background to e.g. red instead of the dynamicsource.

Comment: Add Background = {TemplateBinding Background} to the Grid in the ControlTemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ControlTemplate for local:PopupButton you have a toggle button but you are overring it's template as well. Try removing:

```
<ToggleButton.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
    </ControlTemplate>
</ToggleButton.Template>
```